# Intellij review comments just for private use

Tags: intellij-idea

While working in intellij editor, I want to add small notes for specific code lines, methods or classes. Just like review comments. But only for my reference later. I want to do it without editing the source code. (Like adding TODO or FIXME comments). I think eclipse having bookmarking feature similar to this.

Is there any way or a plugin that I can use for my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

[Bookmarks](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/managing-bookmarks.html) are probably the feature you want.

When you're on a specific line of code, you can either hit the F11 key to mark that line as a bookmark.  You would then have to go to your Favorites tab or hit Shift + F11 to pull up the list of anonymous bookmarks, which you can then add a short description to.

Comment: I tried bookmarks. But it can only include small descriptions. Also we have to add bookmark first and then the comment. I am looking for more simple and powerful thing. Thanks for suggestion anyway.